# Does changing the relative position change how linking to a part of the page works?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a website I am working on where linking to an element with `id="example"` goes to a little further down on the page. I think this may be because I have set `position: relative;` and `top: 100px;`. Is this the problem I have, and if so, how would I fix/circumvent this?

Comment: If you could show your code, we can look at it and see what the error actually is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes exactly correct, The browser will scroll down to match the top edge of the box, The `top` property moves the top edge that's why this is happening.

Quick and dirty fix `padding-top`

```css
p,
h2 {
  height: 50000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

h2 {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#h2">Go to the h2</a>

<p> p tag </p>

<h2 id="h2">The h2</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. If you had set the top at 0px, the element would be at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two cases as far as I understood the question.

1) You are either linking to some element within the same page.

See if there is **id="#example"** any where in your code. If it is there, then remove the ***id="#example"*** from that element and it will not go to that place.

To learn more about linking within the same page of a web document, please read:

https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000049.htm

2) Or it could infact be the **position:relative**; **top:100px**  issue.
   which shifts the element(on which this CSS is applied) **100px** down from its normal position.

Go to the  following link to know more about positioning in CSS:

https://dzone.com/articles/css-position-relative-vs-position-absolute[enter link description here](https://dzone.com/articles/css-position-relative-vs-position-absolute)

Check both the scenarios in your code and hopefully it will resolve your issue :)